# How to count the occurence of each number in list A that is exist in list B and return zero if not existed?

Tags: c#, linq

This is my first question in this community and I would like to get an answer to my problem ,
Suppose that I have two lists A and B:

```
List<int> listA = new List<int>();
List<int> listB = new List<int>();

listA.Add(1);
listA.Add(2);
listA.Add(8);


listB.Add(1);
listB.Add(1);
listB.Add(1);
listB.Add(2);
listB.Add(2);
listB.Add(2);
listB.Add(2);
```

I would like to count the occurrences of each element in listB that already existed in listA and add zero if does not exist:

This is what I've tried:

```
var result = listB.GroupBy(x => x).ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Count());
foreach(var res in result.Values)
    Console.WriteLine(res); // it will print only {3,4}
```

The expected result will be :

```
// { 3,4,0}  => 3 is the occurrences number of 1 , 4 is the occurrences number of 2 ,and 0 is the number occurrences of 8
```

How can I achieve this result?

Comment: What have you tried already? This is not a homework service?

Comment: Please check the update

Comment: You need to include the code that generates my list.

Comment: myList is the same as ListB , I've updated my code.

Comment: notice that your attempt does not refer to listA at all, that should be a clue as to why it doesnt work. Clue instead of looping over result, loop over listA and look in result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the linq .Count() extension, which will count the number of items that satisfy a condition. Yes, this will iterate the list more times than is necessary, but it doesn't create any unnecessary objects, and it is very readable:

```
var countOccurences = new List<int>();
        
foreach (var inA in listA)
{
    countOccurences.Add(listB.Count(inB => inB == inA));
}
    
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", countOccurences));
```

Once you've got the loop working, then it should be easy to see that it can be done in a single statement:

```
var countOccurences = listA.Select(inA => listB.Count(inB => inA == inB));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a good problem to use left outer join in LINQ. Here is an [article about it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-left-outer-joins). It's the best performance solution because you iterate over the collection just once and it's important for big collections or frequently used methods.

Here is an example for your problem:

```
var result = from a in listA
    join b in listB.GroupBy(x => x) on a equals b.Key into gj
    from subList in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new
    {
        Number = a,
        Count = subList?.Count() ?? 0
    };
```

You can also use GroupJoin and method chaining but I think that it's much harder to read:

```
var result = listA
    .GroupJoin(listB.GroupBy(x => x), a => a, b => b.Key, (a, gj) => new { a, gj })
    .SelectMany(@t => @t.gj.DefaultIfEmpty(), (@t, subList) => new { Number = @t.a, Count = subList?.Count() ?? 0 });
```

After that result will contains a collection of anonymous types with fields `Number` and `Count` with 3 elements: `{1, 3}, {2, 4}, {8, 0}`.

Update from comments (thanks to Caius Jard): if you can't use [Null-Conditional Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/october/csharp-the-new-and-improved-csharp-6-0#null-conditional-operator) you may just replace it with explicit check: `subList == null ? 0 : subList.Count()`

Comment: Did you have other solution? I can't use `?`

Comment: @Dotnet_Developer10 use `subList == null ? 0 : subList.Count()` then

Answer (score 0):

fixing your code

```
var result = listB.GroupBy(x => x).ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Count());
foreach(var ent in listA)
    Console.WriteLine(result.ContainsKey(ent)?result[ent]:0);
```

Comment: ToLookup would be a slightly more terse option here

Comment: @CaiusJard TIL that `Lookup<>` exists - TY

Answer (score 0):

one line Linq statment

```
listA.Select(a => listB.Contains(a) ? a : 0 ).Select(r=>listB.Count(w=> w==r)).ToList();
```